# Get call history programmatically in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an *iOS* application using iOS 6. I need to get the *call history* from the iOS device programmatically. I've tried my best and got a solution but it only works in below iOS 5.
Is it possible in above iOS 5 or in iOS 6?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your current solution?

Comment: OP says he tried [this.](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)

Comment: visit http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/
I get the call history in iOS 4 But it not works in iOS 5 and more than iOS 5 .please help me.

Comment: @HardikRami You know, Apple doesn't let you do that anymore intentionally...

Answer (score 1):

in my ios5 device, the call log location is

> "/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db"

and here is my code to retrieve call log

```
- (void)getCallHistory
{  
    self.callHistories = [NSMutableArray array];

FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db"];

    NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];

if([db open]) {
    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select address, date, flags, duration from call order by date"];
    while ([rs next]) {
        int dateInt = [rs intForColumn:@"date"];
        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:dateInt];
        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"];
        NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:date];

        int flagsInt = [rs intForColumn:@"flags"];
        NSString *flags = @"?";
        switch (flagsInt) {
            case 4: flags = @"<-"; break;
            case 5: flags = @"->"; break;
            default: break;
        }

        int durationInt = [rs intForColumn:@"duration"];
        NSString *duration = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", durationInt / 60, durationInt % 60];

        NSString *logLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ (%@)", dateString, flags, [rs stringForColumn:@"address"], duration];
        [callHistories addObject:logLine];
    }
    [rs close];

    rs = [db executeQuery:@"select bytes_rcvd, bytes_sent from data where pdp_ip = 0"];
    while ([rs next]) {
        double bytes_sent = [rs doubleForColumn:@"bytes_sent"];
        double bytes_rcvd = [rs doubleForColumn:@"bytes_rcvd"];

        self.prettyBytesSent = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:bytes_sent] prettyBytes];
        self.prettyBytesReceived = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:bytes_rcvd] prettyBytes];
    }

    [rs close];

    [db close];
    }

}
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You not get call history bcoz in ios 5 call_history.db not in read mode.so you not read this call_history.db flie.you only read this database in jailbreak.

Comment: ok agree in ios 5 call_history.db but what is location of call_history.db in ios5 or ios6