# Get call history programmatically in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios8, jailbreak

I am trying to get the call history programmatically on iOS 8 as an in-house app targeting jailbroken devices. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178382/get-call-history-programmatically-in-ios-6) question had the solution.

**Problem:** Database directory has changed in iOS 8. Rather than

```
/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db
```

its now

```
/var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB/CallHistory.storedata
```

And if I use new database file on FMDB I get "permission denied". So far as I can tell its caused because sandboxed apps are logged in as "mobile" user and are not allowed to reach

```
/var/mobile/Library
```

**Tried:** Moving the `CallHistory.storedata` to old directory where `call_history.db` is located (as root). It works within the app that way. But I need my app to function on its own and copying files again are not permitted within app.

Is there any way I can let my app get permissions for `/var/mobile/Library` or any other solutions from experienced jailbreak developers?

Comment: If you're targeting jailbroken devices then you can install your app outside of the sandbox and access anything you want.

Comment: @creker i was not able to find out how I was supposed to do that, you have any links you can redirect me?

Comment: @Bartu See [compiling for Cydia submission](http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submit-your-app/compile-for-cydia-submission). You should also be able to build your app normally, and just create a .deb off of it. IIRC, debs are some mix of tar, xz, and ar, plus a few meta files. Not too hard to derive if you can download and inspect a few debs (and there's plenty at [apt.saurik.com](http://apt.saurik.com/debs/)). If at some point you're not sure what kind of data you're dealing with, try the `file` command.

Comment: @Siguza i was able to solve the issue by creating an external service to move the files to a non-restricted place as administrator to be able to use it within app sandbox. Thanks for the help.